# Getting a date from a string text with re.findall()

Tags: python, regex, string, findall

I'm trying to extract dates from a whole string text. But I have not any idea how to solve this problem:

The format of dates that I'm finding is *19 Oct. 20* or *19 Oct. 2020*

To achieve that I use the following code:

```
'''re.findall(r'\d*\d (?:%s)\.? \d{2,4}\b' % '|'.join(m.title().rstrip('.') for m in calendar.month_abbr[1:]),string)'''
```

The problem comes when something like this appears in the text: *19 Oct 16:35* and `re.findall()` returns `19 Oct 16`.

How can I get it to only return what I am looking for?

Thanks!

Comment: Which characters (a colon being one) cannot immediately follow a two-digit year?

Comment: why `19 Oct 16` not valid ? can't trust anychar after year ? use `\d{2,4}(?!\S)`

Comment: @Edward: because the 16 there is part of a time, not a year in this particular case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may fail the match if there is a colon and digit after two digits:

```
r'\d*\d (?:%s)\.? (?:\d{4}\b|\d{2}\b(?!:\d))'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2ol1Eh/2)

The `(?:\d{4}\b|\d{2}\b(?!:\d))` will match either four digits followed with a word boundary, or two digits also followed with a word boundary but not followed with `:` and a digit.